# Halegannada/Proto-South Dravidian Phonological Changes

Tags: historical-linguistics, comparative-linguistics, dravidian, indian-languages

What is the explanation behind the /p/ to /h/ phonological change from Halegannada to Kannada?

Comment: I have added more tags. Are the "closers" happy now?

Comment: Wikipedia doesn't indicate [Kannada as having a /h/ phoneme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kannada#Phonology). Can you please [edit] this to explain more.

Comment: @curiousdannii: Kannada ಹ is /h/, not /ħ/. Listen to the recording here: https://www.omniglot.com/writing/kannada.htm

Comment: @fdb I'm not good at phonology, and definitely wouldn't trust my ears hearing a recording. But while it would be easy for someone else to simplify and say that it represents /h/ instead of /ħ/, it's not reasonable, I don't think, to think that a Wikipedia editor would mistakenly use the much rarer symbol instead of the common one, unless that's what other linguists have actually analysed the sound as.

Comment: @curiousdannii. Trusting your ears is much better idea than trusting all the rubbish on Wikipedia.

Comment: @fdb Those recordings sound like an English speaker. Their retroflex consonants didn't sound like retroflexes to me, and that's a sound I can distinguish. And seeing as the page they're on says /h/, of course it sounds like /h/! Omniglot is an anonymously authored un-editable site - Wikipedia is strictly superior to it in this case. If you can find a peer reviewed article that would be better of course.

Comment: @curiousdannii The German Wikipedia article says it is /h/ (it is written independently of the English version) https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kannada

Comment: @jknappen Which is also unreferenced. So I went and looked up [Steever's chapter in The Dravidian Languages](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=6WDxBwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA1&pg=PT174#v=onepage&q&f=false) who says that it's velar, not pharyngeal. Still odd that the Eng Wikipedia says the later. There must be another source somewhere saying that.

Comment: @curiousdannii. If there are no minimal pairs for [h] versus [ħ] then you can in any case consider them as allophones of the phoneme /h/.

Comment: @curiousdannii  both phonemes are allophones in Kannada.

Answer (score 6):

Kannada is not unique in this. Indo-European *p becomes h in Armenian, as in hair "father".

Comment: Also, Indo-European *p disappeared in Celtic, and (at least according to some authorities) early Japanese *p became /h/.

Answer (score 6):

As @fdb already noted, this sound change is not rare cross-linguistically. It is typically not a one step process but a chain of sound shifts /p/ -> /pʰ/ -> /f/ or /ɸ/ -> /h/ (and finally /h/ -> nothing; as observed in the evolution of the Celtic languages from Proto-Indogermanic).

All the steps are frequently attested in isolation, e.g., /p/ -> /f/ from Proto-Semitic to Arabic, or from Proto-Indogermanic to Proto-Germanic;  /f/ -> /h/ for Spanish.

Answer (score 0):

Before listing possible reasons for the change, below mentioned facts should be considered:

1) We can't pronounce words with /p/ much louder compare to /h/ (Try shouting Pogu and Hogu and observe  the difference).

2) Not all the /p/ to /h/ phonological change occurred in Kannada.
-Rarely used words are not changed (ex: Pashana(means poison)).
-Words used in literatures are not changed (ex: Panditya, Prakara, Prashamse).

3) Labour class people using common words are mainly changed (Haru, Hattu).

4) Other Dravidian language still retain /p/ instead of /h/ changes.
-Tulu, Tamil and Malayalam still retain /p/ in same words (ex: Pola/Po instead of Hogu).

**Possible Reasons:**

Geographical terrain plays major role in change behind /p/ to /h/

-Kannada speaking area is called [Bayalu Seeme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayalu_Seeme) which means plain ground, this area is surrounded by [Western ghats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Ghats) and [Eastern ghats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Ghats) and hence difficult to maintain communication with surrounding Tamil, Malayalam and Tamil people.

-In large agricultural ground area need to speak in louder with someone in longer distance(Now also construction workers from Bayalu seeme speak loudely).

Comment: I think Adam Farris was asking about phonetic (articulatory or acoustic) mechanisms, Karthik. All language change has its distribution affected by geographical factors, but it's difficult to sustain an argument that a particular change did or didn't happen because of them. It's also difficult to support the argument that a particular change happened because people needed to speak louder. And I'm guessing that the literary words you refer to are mostly borrowed from Sanskrit, and borrowings often do not exhibit the sound changes of the rest of the language.

Answer (score -1):

This phenomenon is called debuccalization. Generally, this phonetic mutation is contextual. For example, in Berber (see Chenwi language) or Germanic (e.g.: hundred), it occurs in word-initial position. These debuccalized sounds had generally a primary or secondary posterior articulatory. So, maybe, your 'p' is not just a [p], but an aspirated consonant.

Comment: Germanic languages didn't shift /p/ -> /h/. German *hundred* is cognate to Latin *centum*, there is a regular sound correspondence German /h/ ~ Latin /k/.

Comment: Where do I said that Germanic /h/ shifted from *p? I am talking about debuccalization. Any sound that became a pharyngeal or glottal consonant. For example, in some Berber languages, initial [t] is pronounced [h] (tamttut > hamttut = woman). I am trying to widen this subject, not just focusing on p > h.

Comment: I just wanted to be crystal clear here because the original question was specifically about the shift /p/ -> /h/.

Comment: @jknappen. Exactly.